# Add formula to cells that already have value's in them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet I am working on and there are cells that already have different values in them. I would like to add a formula, which is *rate, which will multiply the existing values in the cells by the cell named "rate". Is this possible to do without adding the formula to each individual cell. There are over 400 values, in which they need this formula added. Any ideas? I am using Microsoft Office 2019. Basically what I am doing here is attempting to convert all the cells from RMB to USD, by adding a check box, where you click it and it converts the cells to USD, but i can only get this to work by having this formula in each cell. I appreciate any idea's you might have.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Say our values are in **A1** through **A10** and the rate is in cell **B1**:

[image]

Running the short macro:

```
Sub applyRate()
    Range("B1").Name = "Rate"
    For Each r In Range("A1:A10")
        r.Formula = "=RATE*" & r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

Once complete, you can edit the rate cell if the rate changes.

Answer (score 1):

`bkraines`'s answer DOES work, which rather surprised me. But it only does if one has an active formula in the target cell. (It can be a resolvable one, like `=A1` rather than a more open-ended one like `RAND()` but if it is a "label" rather than a formula then the approach does not work in the way you desire. It performs the multiplication (or any of the other three arithmetic operations PSM will perform) and places the result in the cell, not the value that was there times the multiplier. So PSM-ing "23" by "*rate" (if rate = 0.05) yields "1.15" not "23*rate".

However, you can do it with formulas. You'll need, say, three temporary helper columns (delete them when done). In the first, place `"'="` (double quote, single quote, equal sign, double quote). In the second, place "*rate" (asterisk then *rate* bookended by the double quotes around them). It will seem like you can drop this last pair of double quotes, but it will fail if you do. The first one is the string you're adding to the beginning of the original entry and the second is what you're adding to the end of the original entry.

Say those are cells A1 (original entry), B1, and C1. Now in D1 place the formula:

```
=B1&A1&C1
```

Copy/Paste those three cells down as far as you need. Then select the cells in column D and copy them. Return to A1 and `Paste|Special|Values`. Now you have the basics of your result in the original cells... just need to remove the extras. A cell might look like this:

```
'"'="23*rate
```

To finish up, select all those cells and perform two `Find and Replace` operations. Very important to do them in this order:

1. Find and Replace the single quotes with `nothing` (leave the Replace line empty).
2. Find and Replace the double quotes with `nothing` (leave the Replace line empty).

You now will have entries like the following:

```
=23*rate
```

and since they are real boys, er... formulas... now, you will see their results displayed on the screen.

Finally, delete the helper columns. You now have what you wanted:  the original entries preserved in place now multiplied by "rate" and displaying the results. (And with no helper columns lying about uglifying your sheet.)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. First select all cells where formula results should be, then type the formula normally in the first cell, and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

And also you can do: If all the cells are in the same column, type the formula after the first cell, then hold the bottom-right corner of the first cell where the formula is entered and drag to the all cells where the results should be.

And if your purpose is to overwrite the first two columns with new results, just delete the first column. Suppose the first values are in `A1:A10`, and the results are in `B1:B10`, then if you delete `A` column, `B` column will automatically take place of `A` column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this, but it seems to copy the first cell in all the other cells, but since all the cells have different value's, that wont work.

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of your spreadsheet, or if you cannot or you don't like to show, then create a similar spreadsheet and show it to us?

Comment: Hi, I included the screenshot of the spreadsheet, "rate is cell a6"

Comment: have you had chance to take a look?

Comment: Then try formula `=A6*E1` and apply as the amswer

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a bunch of different formulas in column `A` and you want to append `*rate` to all of them. Here's a dirty solution that takes just a few keystrokes. Type `999999` into an empty cell and copy it. Now select the range of formulas in column `A` and pull up the Paste Special dialog, which you can do by hitting `Alt-H`,`V`,`S`. Choose `Formula` and `Multiply` as follows:

[image: paste special dialog]

After hitting `OK`, a formula in column `A` that used to say `=RAND()` will now say `=(RAND())*999999`. Now, with your formulas in column `A` still selected, pull up the Find and Replace dialog (`Ctrl-H`) and replace `999999` with `rate` as follows:

[image: find replace dialog]

Your formulas in column `A` should now say `=(RAND())*rate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think all the answers are so overcomplicated. Why don't you just compute the values (e.g. =A6*E1) in separate cells, then paste the newly computed values AS VALUES in the original cell and remove the helper cells.

Comment: And what about thousands of values?

Comment: The same thing but fix E1 like $E$1.